# Multithreaded Twitter access through Twitter4J

Tags: java, multithreading, twitter, twitter4j

I have written the following Java code:

```
twitterStream.addListener(new StreamListener());

FilterQuery filterQuery = new FilterQuery();
filterQuery.follow(filteringUsers);
filterQuery.track(filteringWords);

twitterStream.filter(filterQuery);
```

to track some users and keywords in Twitter (via the Streaming API). Here, `StreamListener` is my personal implementation of the listener.

I am tracking a lot of keywords, hashtags and users, and thus I accumulate in memory a lot of tweets waiting to be processed. In fact, I am just taking them through the listener (in the `onStatus()` method) and flushing them in the database.

Still, the fact that they have to wait in memory obviously **saturates the memory** in some hours. In 20 minutes run I accumulated in memory 177000 `LinkedBlockingQueue$Node` objects and 1.272MB of `char[]` (seen through profiling).

I would like to keep the pipeline running continuously, and obviously this is not possible in the current status.

Thus, I would like to know whether there is a way of adding multiple listeners in multithreading, so that they can concurrently empty the queue of tweets and speed up the processing.

1. **In case it is possible:** do these listeners empty the queue concurrently? I mean: could it there be the case that they read the same tweet multiple times?
2. **In case it is not possible:** how can I solve my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although a direct multithreaded solution is not possible through Twitter4J, one could decide to simulate a multithreaded queue handling through the listener class.

Suppose `StreamListener` is your specialization of the `StatusListener` Twitter4J listener.

We replicate the queue inside `StreamListener`, as a private attribute:

```
private LinkedBlockingQueue<String> tweets;
```

The queue is initialized in the constructor:

```
tweets = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
```

Moreover, in the constructor we build a thread pool meant to read tweets from the queue (in batches) and store them in the database:

```
    final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);
    Runnable tweetAnalyzer = defineMonitoringRunnable(tweetRepository);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        executor.execute(tweetAnalyzer);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(THREADS_DELAY);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

where the `Runnable` object can be built as follows:

```
private Runnable defineMonitoringRunnable(final TweetRepository tweetRepository) {
    return new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            List<String> tempTweets = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (true) {
                if (tweets.size() > 0) {
                    tempTweets.clear();
                    tweets.drainTo(tempTweets);

                    tweetRepository.insert(tempTweets);   
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(TWEETS_SAVING_TIME);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    };
}
```

(`TWEETS_SAVING_TIME` is the waiting time of each `Thread` object between one tweet saving and another)

Finally, the `onStatus()` method stores tweets in the queue once they arrive to the listener:

```
@Override
public void onStatus(Status status) {   
    tweets.add(TwitterObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status));
}
```